# How to specify ghc version in cabal or stack file

Tags: cabal, haskell-stack

How does one specify which compiler to use in the cabal or stack file of a haskell project.

I tried to add the compiler and with-compiler field as in the documentation however, I get an error 'unknown field compiler'